# Gradient Border Causing the Border to Disappear

Tags: css, border, gradient

I have a few titles (`h3` tags) on my page with a double border to the right of the titles. I want those borders to fade off. I thought I could use gradients on the border to do this but it doesn't work.

To better understand take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/qdo9q4tj/) of the double border. I want those two lines to fade out as it moves right.

Here is the code I am using to create the two lines:

***HTML***

```
<div class="title">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="title-container">
        <div class="title-separator"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.title h3{
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: pre;
    padding-right:7px;
}
.title-container {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
.title-separator {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    height: 6px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: relative;
    border-color:#222;
    border-style:solid;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

What I have attempted to do is use `border-image` by adding the following code to `.title-separator` CSS:

```
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(25,50,39,1) 0%,rgba(17,34,27,0) 100%);
```

(I omitted the vendor prefixes for this post.)

When I do this the border disappears. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/ya8jh33m/) with the gradient code.

Any ideas on how to make the double border fade off? I can change the HTML and/or CSS as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by applying `linear-gradients` to `:after` and `:before` :pseudo-elements.

```css
.title h3 {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: pre;
  padding-right: 7px;
}
.title-container {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}
.title-container:after, .title-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50% + 3px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.title-container:before {
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="title-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this property as

```
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(25,50,39,1) 0%,rgba(17,34,27,0) 100%) 100% 100;
```

may it help you